# Difference b/w "More Than Once" & "Twice"

Tags: meaning-in-context

So if a person is sure that this thing happened twice...he'd rather say 'twice'...when should he say 'more than once'?

Comment: When he knows it was *at least* once, but is unsure whether it was two, three etc occasions.

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe the expression you're describing is *at least once*. *More than once* means the person knows it was *at least twice*, but they're unsure as to the exact number of reoccurrences (i.e., two or three, or more).

Answer (score 1):

Literally, **more than once** means "more than one time", but it is frequently used as understatement with the implication of "too many times".

> The dog has eaten your homework more than once, Ms Jones.

This could have been the second, third, or even the fourth time Ms Jones had used that excuse—and even once was, as we say, *more than enough*.